Como puedo agregar un if dentro de otro if
Hola a todos tengo un if con resultados pero yo quiero agragar otro if dentro de el ejemplo.
codpublix sera de 5 diferentes de codigo
introducir el código aquí

let publix = (this.customers[0].id);
let codpublix = ('b1d37b65-3c20-46da-ebbf-08dc3e01e0aa');
if (publix = codpublix){


}

gracias por la ayuda
segundo if
totalLbs += temptotalLbs;

   

if (temptotalLbs > 0) {
fillingInLbs = temptotalLbs * 0.62 + 10;
} else {
fillingInLbs = 0;
}

jose pereira

Que has intentado?

Tu primer if está mal, tienes UN =, debes usar == o === para una igualdad estricta
